# WCF Project Can't Find Connection String

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, wcf

There is an issue with my application connecting to the database server when a service hits my endpoint. I am testing by using a console app in the same solution with the web service app.  Then the web service app connects to the app that calls to the database using GetCourseDetails method.

```
  public ApiResponse RunCourseReports()
    {
        ApiResponse api = new ApiResponse();
        List<string> Errors = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            LCVista.Models.Courses report = new LCVista.Models.Courses();
            report.ParseCourseDetailsFromSumtotal();


        //    if (Errors.Count > 0)
        //    {
        //        throw new Exception();

        //    }
        //    api.Message = "";
        //    api.Status = "Success";
          return api;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            api.Status = "Error" + e.Message.ToString();
            api.Message = e.Message;
            //api.Message = "Error";

            return api;
        }
        }
```

It tries to get the courses using Entity Framework with this:

```
 public List<tblStage_Course_Details> GetCourseDetails()
    {
        List<tblStage_Course_Details> courseDetailsList = new List<tblStage_Course_Details>();

        try
        {
            using (var context = new CourseDetailsContext())
            {
                List<tblStage_Course_Details> courseDetailsLista = (context.tblStage_Course_Details.Where(s => s.Processed == false)).ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string message = e.Message;
            string api = "Course Details";
            SaveErrors(message, api, "Getting Course Details", "error");
        }


        return courseDetailsList;
    }
```

I get an exception saying the "No connection string named 'CourseDetailsContext' could be found in the application config file."

The CourseDetailsContext is below:

```
 public partial class CourseDetailsContext : DbContext
{
    public CourseDetailsContext()
        : base("name=CourseDetailsContext")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<tblStage_Course_Details> tblStage_Course_Details { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<tblStage_Course_Details>()
            .Property(e => e.Code)
            .IsUnicode(false);
```

All Web Config files have the connections string for CourseDetailsContext. I tested the connection string and it works.  The issue is something with the Console app calling the web service in my project not communicating the connection string.

Comment: The console would not communicate a connection string, it would be the web service's web.config which would be expected to contain the connection string. Though it's not clear when you say "Then the web service app connects to the app that calls to the database". What do you mean by this? How is the web service "connecting" to the app? Is it accessing an object via reference? (in which case the connection string would be in the web service) or some other communication channel? (The connection string would belong with that other app)

Comment: @StevePy GetCourseDetails() is in the app that processes the information. When testing, I use a console app to call the WCF project. This project then connects to the app with GetCourseDetails().  In production a service will call the WCF app to run GetCourseDetails() to get the courses out of the database. All the Web Configs have the connection string. I'm using EF 6.

Comment: Yes, but how does the WCF project connect to that app? Is it a reference to another assembly (References) or calling through something like named pipes?

Comment: It is a reference

Comment: So you have the CourseDetailsContext connection string declared in your WCF web service web.config? (This is where it will be expected to be)  This will be in the main folder of the WCF service, and declared in a connectionStrings section. I.e. `  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CourseDetailsContext" connectionString="{connection string}"/>
  </connectionStrings>` not `<applicationSettings>` or the like.

Comment: @StevePy You're right asking me that question because the connection strings I found out were not in the web config.  I missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your connection String to the App.config of your console app and install Entity Framework on your console app.

Comment: Your correct I missed that too.  I have a mess on the project here and missed the connections strings on the WCF and the Console when testing on my local.